# R - can I write this loop as a apply function?

Tags: r, apply

I've created the following loop but would like to write it as a lapply function.
Is this possible? I'm trying to get my head around apply functions but haven't quite got the hang of it yet.

```
Decay <- function(x, decay=y) stats::filter(x, decay, method = "recursive")

d<-iris[,c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width","Petal.Length","Petal.Width")]

DecayX <- c(0.1,0.3,0.6,0.8,0.95)
DecVars = c("Sepal.Length","Petal.Width")

for (j in DecVars){
  for (i in DecayX){
    VarName <- paste(colnames(d[j]),i*100,"DEC",sep="_")
    d[[VarName]]<-Decay(d[j],i)
  }
}
```

Comment: please explain a bit what you want to do with your code. Add the expected output as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. The expected output is a dataframe with 10 new columns (5 decays * 2 variables). If you run all of the above it should work. It is supposed to loop through the variables names and decays rates. However I've been reading and I understand that lapply or mapply is a lot better way of doing this type of thing, so keep to understand a way of doing it that way

Comment: thats weird. its working on mine. It needs all the code to be run, as the decay function is build into the loop.

Comment: @Jimbou I have added the reference for stats:: package. You filter is probably masked by dplyr::filter.

Comment: @fred: Whats wrong with your code? Is it running to slow? What problem are you encountering. Or you just want to play/practice with `(l)apply` familiy?

Comment: Yeah, no problems with the code. I used to use a lot of VBA, so applied that kind of thinking to the problem. I've  been doing some reading and people suggest you should use lapply or mapply instead of loops, when using R. So was trying to play around with that, and get the same output

Comment: sounds like this isn't the right problem for that sort of application

Comment: please see my edit. My solution gives you the same result ... but look at it. Its difficult to read and probably not faster. Your code is just fine!

Comment: Great, thanks a lot of for your help on this!! I'll take a look.

Comment: my code is maybe a good example because it contains some probably new functions that you can learn. Also, have a look what `<<-` does.

Comment: great, will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any reason to use the apply family here.

You could use `mapply`

```
vars <- c(expand.grid(DecayX,DecVars,stringsAsFactors = F))
invisible(
mapply(function(x,DecV){VarName <- paste(colnames(d[DecV]),x*100,"DEC",sep="_");
                        d[[VarName]]<<-Decay(d[DecV],x)},x=vars[[1]],DecV=vars[[2]])
)
```

I think in cases of a double loop I would not use the `apply` family.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to replace each for loop with an `sapply()` which is faster than `for` loops and doesn't require the use of `expand.grid()`.

```
invisible(
  sapply(DecVars, function(j) {
    sapply(DecayX, function(i) {
      VarName <- paste(colnames(d[j]),i*100,"DEC",sep="_")
      d[[VarName]] <<- Decay(d[j],i)
    })
  })
)
```

You can see that this is a lot faster than using `for` loops and also marginally faster than the use of `mapply()` with `grid.expand()`:

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  'mapply' = {
    vars <- c(expand.grid(DecayX,DecVars,stringsAsFactors = F))
    invisible(
      mapply(function(x,DecV){VarName <- paste(colnames(d[DecV]),x*100,"DEC",sep="_");
      d[[VarName]]<<-Decay(d[DecV],x)},x=vars[[1]],DecV=vars[[2]])
    )},
  'sapply' = {
    invisible(
      sapply(DecVars, function(j) {
        sapply(DecayX, function(i) {
          VarName <- paste(colnames(d1[j]),i*100,"DEC",sep="_")
          d1[[VarName]] <<- Decay(d1[j],i)
        })
      })
    )
  },
  'for-loop' = {
    for (j in DecVars){
      for (i in DecayX){
        VarName <- paste(colnames(d[j]),i*100,"DEC",sep="_")
        d[[VarName]]<-Decay(d[j],i)
      }
    }
  },
  times = 1000)
```

Note: if you ignore the `expand.grid()` step, `mapply()` would be marginally faster.